# How to create a symbolic link in C#/NET6.0 using FileInfo.CreateAsSymbolicLink?

Tags: c#, windows, symlink, .net-6.0

Given this snippet running on Windows:

```cs
string filePath = "myfile";
string linkTarget = "myfile.link";

FileInfo finfo = new(filePath);
FileInfo fi = new(linkTarget);

finfo.Create().Close();
Assert.IsTrue(finfo.Exists);

fi.CreateAsSymbolicLink(filePath);
Assert.IsTrue(fi.Exists); // here thrown, assert is false. And LinkTarger == null.
```

the symbolic link is not being created and doesn't exists.

It looks like a .NET6.0 bug to me.

what's wrong with it?

What am I missing?

How can i create a symbolic link using `FileInfo` or related?

**EDIT**

I forgot that must be an admin to create a symbolic link in windows,
besides shouldn't throw instead a "`NotAuthorized`" or something?

At this point if i want to create a symbolic link not as admin won't be possible then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this other
[answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-you-have-to-be-an-admin-to-create-a-symlink-in-windows).
The reason why the file doesn't exists is because the program doesn't run with admin privileges

It looks like there is a policy to set up to allow non admin to create symlinks.